# How to set specific JQuery version using JavaScript Libraries in DNN

Tags: jquery, version, dotnetnuke, libraries

How can I set the specific version of the JQuery I would like to use in Code using JavaScript Libraries in DNN? There are documentation, but it is not specifically showing the exact parameters in brackets.
I had a look at this wiki: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/javascript-libraries#Usage_5

```
JavaScript.RequestRegistration(CommonJs.jQuery, 3.2.1);
```

The number gives an error in VS. To what must I change it to?

Comment: Did you take a look at the error? And what kind of datatype is `3.2.1`? The correct overload is `Version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
JavaScript.RequestRegistration("jQuery", new Version(1, 9, 1));
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in DNN version 8.0.4. I have a AngularJs library with multiple versions but when I specify say 1.5.6 it still pulls the most recent version (1.6.6). I wonder if there was an update I missed?

Comment: Check in \Resources\Libraries that you have an AngularJs folder with folders under it that have the versioned folders: "01_05_06" and "01_06_06".  This should have been done when you installed the javascript library packages.